# how to print values between 2 numbers in APL?

Tags: apl

I am not able to print values ranging from 30 to 50 both inclusive in APL.

Actually I tried so much operators but not working.

Comment: Stating which implementation and version of APL you use, will help people to give you the best response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your constraints? Do you want to define a function or do you just want to know how to iterate? Does "print" mean return as result or literally print to somewhere (output/file)?

In the easiest way, use iota `⍳` to iterate through the distance between the two bounds, then add the lower one to the results. Assuming index origin `IO` is set to `0`:

```
    30 + ⍳21
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

If `IO` is set to `1`, lower the lower bound:

```
    29 + ⍳21
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

You can always inspect or set `IO` using `⎕IO` if you wanted to switch:

```
    ⎕IO ← 0
0
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to print random 12 values between 8 to 30.

Answer (score 1):

> Actually I wanted to print random 12 values between 8 to 30.

If `⎕IO` is set to `1`, you can generate a random integer larger or equal to `1` and smaller or equal to `23` using `?23` (or `?1+30-8`). Then, add `7` (or `8-1`) to the result, and it will be shifted between 8 and 30, both inclusive: `7+?23`. (With `⎕IO` set to `0`, the generated random number will instead range from `0` to `22`, so to reach the destination range you'd have to add `8` rather than `7`, or `(8-⎕IO)` more generically if independence from `⎕IO` is a concern.)

Now, to draw more than one random number from that range, provide `?` in its left argument with the amount of draws you'd like to see. The result is an array of that length.

```
      7+12?23
23 21 9 8 10 27 12 30 28 19 26 14
```

Note that these numbers are all unique (no duplicates). To instead get an array of independent random numbers (values can be drawn more than once), use `⍴` to accordingly reshape the (right) argument of `?` which will then be applied onto the whole array:

```
      7+?12⍴23
9 8 30 16 13 25 26 8 26 19 19 18
```

Answer (score 0):

[@pmf's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053266/5306507) is simple, but can be very inefficient (for two large, but close values) and fails if any number is negative.

If we call the bounds `⍺` and `⍵` then `⍺+¯1+⍳1+⍵-⍺` is both efficient and general. Remove `¯1+` if `⎕IO` is 0. You can create a `to` function using this formula as follows:

```
      to←{(⍺-⎕IO)+¯1+⍳1+⍵-⍺}
      30 to 50
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Alternatively, if you use Dyalog APL, you can use [the `to` utility function](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_to.htm) from the dfns workspace, as follows:

```
      'to' ⎕CY 'dfns'
      30 to 50
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Comment: As regards your first solution, wouldn't `to←{(⍺-⎕IO)+⍳1+⍵-⍺}` solve it agnostically for `⎕IO`?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin It would, of course, but I wanted to keep the formula simple. I'll change the function definition, though.